# Extracting value from xml clob with Namespace using Oracle pl/sql

Tags: xml, oracle, clob

I am currently trying to extract value from the `clob` column but always getting the result as `null`.

I tried out many possible scenarios but for me it is always returning as `null`.

Attached is the actual xml

```
<TenderOffer xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm">
    <Shipment>
        <ShipmentHeader/>
        <SEquipment/>
        <ShipmentStop/>
        <ShipmentStop/>
        <Location/>
        <Location/>
        <Release/>
        <RATE_OFFERING>
            <RATE_OFFERING_ROW>
                <USER_CLASSIFICATION3>ZXF</USER_CLASSIFICATION3>
            </RATE_OFFERING_ROW>
        </RATE_OFFERING>
    </Shipment>
    </TenderOffer>
```

and below is the actual query,

```
select 
        itc.element_name,
        extractvalue(XMLTYPE(XML_BLOB), '/TenderOffer/Shipment/RATE_OFFERING/RATE_OFFERING_ROW/USER_CLASSIFICATION3/text()'),
    XMLTYPE(XML_BLOB)
        from i_transaction itc
        where itc.i_transaction_no = 31553115
            and rownum = 1
```

Comment: Verify your code for typo, I get `abxy` with your query: `SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XMLTYPE('<Header> 
    <SecondHeader>
    <ThirdHeader>
    <FourthHeader>
    <Value1>abcd</Value1>
    <Value2>xyz</Value2>
    <Value3>abxy</Value3>
    </FourthHeader>
    </ThirdHeader>
    </SecondHeader>
</Header>'), '/Header/SecondHeader/ThirdHeader/FourthHeader/Value3/text()')
FROM dual;`

Comment: Hi Mate, i updated the xml and actual query, can you please have a look.Thanks.

Comment: Posting the XML as an image ins't terribly useful, though from that image there aren't any obvious typos. (Why is your column called `xml_blob` if it's a CLOB?). Presumably your query shows the CLOB value you expect, with just the extracted value as null? Can you cut it down to a simpler example that actually reproduces the problem, since your first 'Header' version doesn't?

Comment: Hi Mate, it is clob but the name of the column is xml_blob, is there any way to upload my xml ?

Comment: Cut it down to a minimal example that still shows the problem - remove any nodes that aren't relevant/in the hierarchy, and hide any data you don't want to share. But check that when you run that cut-down version you do still see the same issue.

Comment: Done. can you please check now?

Comment: @AProgrammer - your query with that cut-down XML still works fine for me, I get `ZXF` back. Not sure how you are getting null back from that same text - even if you copy and paste back from this question to your own environment? There seems to be something you aren't showing us or are doing differently without realising.

Comment: Hi Mate, does it have any size restrictions? only difference is you executed from cut-down xml but i did it with whole xml

Comment: if i execute the below query - select 
  itc.element_name,
  --extractvalue(XMLTYPE(XML_BLOB), '/TenderOffer/Shipment/RATE_OFFERING/RATE_OFFERING_ROW/USER_CLASSIFICATION3/text()'),
    Length(XMLTYPE(XML_BLOB)), Length(XML_BLOB)
    from i_transaction itc
  where itc.i_transaction_no = 31553115
   and rownum = 1

then i get the below error,

ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small" 
*Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
*Action:   Get the result as a lob instead

Comment: My xml is 39264 characters.

Comment: Hi Mate any solution for this? do i need to convert it to varchar2 before extracting the values?

Comment: There is no size restriction (well, a very large one, in terabytes) for a CLOB. The error in your previous comment is from trying to get a varchar2 out of your XMLType, which is then too large for that data type. That's nothing to do with your original problem. What happens when *you* run your query with the cut-down version of the XML?

Comment: What do you get from `select *
        from i_transaction itc
        where itc.i_transaction_no = 31553115
            and rownum = 1`?

Comment: the last query returns valid result

Comment: the column xml_blob actually starts with value something like below

<TenderOffer xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm"><Shipment><ShipmentHeader> ...

Comment: Yes, that was rather an important omission... even from what you said was your 'actual XML'. Guess I should have asked. *8-)

Comment: Thanks for the help Alex. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your updated XML has a namespace, which finally reveals the issue. You need to [specify the namespace as part of the XML extraction](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb04cre.htm#GUID-1E1D2966-8995-4BBD-B039-2E6CEB7B275A), which is simpler with the XMLTable approach; in this case you can just treat it as the default namespace:

```
select itc.element_name, x.user_classification3
from i_transaction itc
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces(default 'http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm'),
    '/TenderOffer/Shipment/RATE_OFFERING/RATE_OFFERING_ROW'
  passing xmltype(itc.xml_blob)
  columns user_classification3 varchar2(10) path 'USER_CLASSIFICATION3'
) x
where itc.i_transaction_no = 31553115
and rownum = 1;

ELEMENT_NA USER_CLASS
---------- ----------
dummy      ZXF
```

or with XMLQuery:

```
select itc.element_name, xmlquery(
  'declare default element namespace "http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm"; (: :)
    /TenderOffer/Shipment/RATE_OFFERING/RATE_OFFERING_ROW/USER_CLASSIFICATION3/text()'
  passing xmltype(itc.xml_blob)
  returning content
) x
from i_transaction itc
where itc.i_transaction_no = 31553115
and rownum = 1;

ELEMENT_NA X                                                                               
---------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dummy      ZXF
```

If you wanted to keep using the deprecated `extractvalue()` function you can supply the namespace as an argument to that too, again [as shown in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions069.htm):

```
select itc.element_name,
  extractvalue(xmltype(xml_blob),
    '/TenderOffer/Shipment/RATE_OFFERING/RATE_OFFERING_ROW/USER_CLASSIFICATION3/text()',
    'xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/otm"')
from i_transaction itc where itc.i_transaction_no = 31553115 and rownum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use `XML_BLOB` as the variable - so I assumed a `BLOB` data type, which needs converting to a `CLOB`. However, if you have a `CLOB` value then you can skip using the `BLOB_TO_CLOB` function:

**Oracle 11 Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BLOB_TO_CLOB( b BLOB )
RETURN CLOB 
IS
  c            CLOB;
  n            INTEGER     := 1;
  w   CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
  len CONSTANT INTEGER     := LENGTH( b );
BEGIN
  IF b IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  IF len = 0 THEN
    RETURN EMPTY_CLOB();
  END IF;

  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c, TRUE );
  WHILE ( n + w <= len ) LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c, w, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( b, w, n ) ) );
    n := n + w;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c, len - n + 1, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( b, len - n + 1, n ) ) );
  RETURN c;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE blob_test ( value BLOB );

INSERT INTO blob_test VALUES (
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(
    '<Header>' ||
      '<SecondHeader>' ||
        '<ThirdHeader>' ||
          '<FourthHeader>' ||
            '<Value1>abcd</Value1>' ||
            '<Value2>xyz</Value2>' ||
            '<Value3>abxy</Value3>' ||
          '</FourthHeader>' ||
        '</ThirdHeader>' ||
      '</SecondHeader>' ||
    '</Header>'
  )
);
```

**Query**:

`EXTRACT` and `EXTRACTVALUE` are deprecated - use `XMLTABLE` instead:

```
SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3
FROM   blob_test b
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/Header/SecondHeader/ThirdHeader/FourthHeader'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( BLOB_TO_CLOB( b.value ) )
         COLUMNS Value1 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'Value1/text()',
                 Value2 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'Value2/text()',
                 Value3 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'Value3/text()'
       ) x;
```

**Output**:

```
VALUE1 VALUE2 VALUE3
------ ------ ------
abcd   xyz    abxy
```

**Query 2**:

If you do want to use `EXTRACTVALUE` you can remove the `/text()` from the XPath as `EXTRACTVALUE` will do that for you (but it should still work with it there too) and convert the `BLOB` to a `CLOB`:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(
         XMLTYPE( BLOB_TO_CLOB( value ) ), 
         '/Header/SecondHeader/ThirdHeader/FourthHeader/Value3'
       )
FROM   blob_test
```

**Query - Update**:

Simplification from [@AlexPoole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole). The call to `BLOB_TO_CLOB` is not necessary as the [`XMLTYPE` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71992) can take a `BLOB` and a character set id:

```
SELECT Value1, Value2, Value3
FROM   blob_test b
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/Header/SecondHeader/ThirdHeader/FourthHeader'
         PASSING XMLTYPE( b.value, NLS_CHARSET_ID('UTF8') )
         COLUMNS Value1 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'Value1/text()',
                 Value2 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'Value2/text()',
                 Value3 VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'Value3/text()'
       ) x;
```

Comment: Bit of a side issue, as the OP indicated the column is a CLOB despite the name (!), but you don't have to convert the BLOB first anyway as long as you know the character set to pass to the XMLType constructor - e.g. `xmltype(xml_blob, nls_charset_id('UTF8'))`.

Comment: @AlexPoole In the first paragraph I did address that discrepancy and opted to address the more complicated of the two possible versions and added the note that for a `CLOB` you can just remove the call to `BLOB_TO_CLOB`. However, it is good to know the additional argument for `XMLType`.

Comment: Yes, it's just an alternative if it *is* a BLOB - I was just adding that the more complicated scenario still doesn't necessarily need the `blob_to_clob` function, which incidentally uses the DB character set. It's a useful one to have around anyway of course.